# mysql_num_rows() Input Validation

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some values into a mysql database, and before I insert I want to check if one of the input fields has a value that is already in the database before I allow the insert.

When I run the script I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

and the error points back to this line in my PHP:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE tape_no='$tape_no'";
$result = $dbLink->query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
if($result) {
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
echo '<html>';
     echo '<head>';
echo '<link href="/module.css" rel="stylesheet type="text/css" />';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
echo '<h3>The Tape Number That You Have Entered is a Duplicate, Please Choose Another Tape Number</h3>';
echo '<FORM><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" class="bluebutton" VALUE="Go Back" ONCLICK="history.go(-1)"></FORM>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
}
@mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

Does the column that I am referencing need to be of a certain data type (ie. Integer) ? Will a varchar column type work here?

Comment: What PHP extension you're using to connect to MySQL? You seem to be using `ext/MySQLi` in some places, but `ext/mysql` in others

Comment: You seem to be using a custom class to handle DB queries (`$dbLink->query($qry)`) - this class should provide you with the necessary function to check the number of rows. You are trying to use a function that expects a resource - such as one returned from `mysql_query`

Comment: Did you try to debug the $result variable before use it? I'll try to simulate this here to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction

PHP ships with two *distinct* MySQL-specific API extensions:

- [MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), supporting procedural style only (`mysql_query()`);
- [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), supporting OO style (`mysqli::query()`) and procedural style (`mysqli_query()`);
- There are also vendor-nonspecific abstraction layers, such as [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

---

#### Your problem

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Well, it's not one.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

expects that `$result` is a result resource as obtained through the MySQL series of functions.

However, in your code, it's most likely a result from some other extension. Unless you've written some leaky abstraction layer, you're mixing two different extensions!

(You're going to have the same problem with `mysql_free_result($result)`. Read the documentation for whichever extension you're using.)

---

#### Your solution

If using MySQLi, try:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

If using PDO, try:

```
if ($result->rowCount > 0)
```

Comment: While it is reasonable to assume it is mysqli, it might also be PDO.

Comment: ...or it might be just a wrapper.

Comment: Tomalak, thanks for taking the time for the explanation, that was the correct solution.

Comment: @matt: No problem. Out of interest, what extension _are_ you using?

Comment: @Tomalak. Little embarrasing, but it was MySQLi extension. Palm slap to my forehead, learned my lesson today! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing 2 different mysql resources. As there is no way that you used

```
$result = $dbLink->query($qry)
```

And received a `mysql` result set (`mysql_*` doesn't support OOP). Here's how I'd do it in PDO

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE tape_no='$tape_no'";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
if (!$stmt) { throw new Exception("Query was not complete."); }
if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
     //Good Stuff
}
```